# Spring Data JPA + openjpa: Is it possible to join a table not in OR-Hierarchy?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So, the following usecase:

I've got two tables and the corresponding entities, lets call them table A (the left) and table B (the right). Both tables have a column "size", but at my OR-Model, table a has no reference to an object of table b.
Now what I want to achieve (via Spring Data JPA @Query-Annotation / JPQL, not using native SQL) is something like the following (a little simplified) Query:

```
@Query("select a from TheLeftTable a join TheRightTable b" +
       "where b.size = a.size ")
Page<TheLeftTable> findAllAvailableEntries(Pageable p);
```

but i get the following exception cause when trying to start my tomcat:

> ...Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "join TheRightTable b" at character 48, but expected: [".", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", ]

So my Question is: Is this generally possible or not to create such a query with JPQL / JPA only? Please remember: In My OR-Model, TableA has no Object from Table B. My simplified Entitiy-Properties are looking just like this:

```
@Column(name = "size")
String size;
```

If it is not possible, any other ideas would be great. (Except changing my Entity for Table A to have the object of Entity B, which is sadly not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, it is possible to do that:

```
SELECT a FROM TheLeftTable a, TheRightTable b WHERE b.size = a.size
```

It is called cross join, but if the columns `size` are indexed, you won't notice it any performance issues.